# Early Experiments In Electrodynamics

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, history, batteries

Before the electric power grid, what were Ampere, Faraday, Coulomb, et. al using to study electricity?

In everything I read, it just kind of says "____ noticed that when wires carrying a charge came near each other" or something of the sort, but nothing really talks about how they were generating current through these wires in the first place.

Comment: What sources have you consulted? Do you recognise the term Voltaic pile?

Comment: @AndersSandberg As far as I understand, the Voltaic pile came around 1800 and Stephen Gray discovered conductivity before that, but Oersted made his accidental discovery with a wire and compass around 1720; the Ampere (unit) was originally used to designate the amount of current that produces a certain amount of silver in solution, so is the idea that the experimenters of the early 1800's (after the discovery of the battery) were mostly using variants of the Voltaic pile and electrolysis set-ups with the various metals to generate currents they could examine?

Comment: You are off by 100 years. It was 1820 not 1720. Oersted even  invented a new type of battery before his discovery of the electromagnetism.

Comment: @nasu Ah, my mistake, yeah. So the Voltaic pile was really the beginning of what let helped people start studying current more systematically?

Answer (score 1):

Once Volta had developed his pile, the field of electrochemistry started to take off and anyone who could build a wet cell with dissimilar metals and an acid solution could perform their own experiments with electricity.